# I'm having problems relating to template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class RandomIterator, class T>
T median(RandomIterator b, RandomIterator e)
{
    std::sort(b, e);

    int count = 0;

    for(RandomIterator ri = b; ri != e; ++ri)
        ++count;

    int mid = count / 2;

    return (count % 2 == 0) ? *(b+mid) : (*(b+mid) + *(b+mid+1)) / 2;
}
```

I'm having trouble with class T, the return type for the median function. If I take it out and turn T into int, it seems to work but lessens the meaning of using templates. Help!

Comment: *How* doesn't your function work? Do you get build errors? Run-time errors or crashes? Wrong results? And how do you *use* the function? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: On a side note: making `median` function sort the range seems to be a bad idea. First: it is a surprise for the caller, secondly you can find median in one pass of the range, hence reducing the complexity. If you want to use median function on sorted ranges, you should probably define a function `median_on_sorted` and assume that the input has been sorted. Lastly, you should use `std::distance` instead of doing a pass of whole array (again suboptimal, `std::distance` should be O(1) in your case).

Comment: I'd be wary of assuming that `+` and `/` are valid operations for your elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your actual question, the issue with templates is that the compiler needs to be able to figure out what the type `T` is just from the function call.  It can't do this because `T` is never used directly, and certainly not in the function signature (which excludes the return type).

### Slight improvement

One approach is to explicitly state it when calling, e.g. `median<std::vector<double>::iterator, double>(mvvec.begin(), myvec.end());` but that is rather unwieldy.  A better option would be to swap the order of `RandomIterator` and `T` in the template declaration so that you can just specify the return type: `median<double>(myvec.begin(), myvec.end());`

### Better improvement

However, in C++11 and later you can do better.  Drop the `class T` in the template and use auto, specifying the iterator's value_type if needed:
`auto median(RandomIterator b, RandomIterator e) -> decltype(*b)`  You may find the decltype is not necessary.  However you also need to be sure whether you want to return a a value or a reference - there are pros and cons each way so I can't decide for you.

### Best approach

However, your function is unusual in that it both operates on a range (pair of iterators) yet returns a value.  Most STL algorithms return an iterator, because they can't be sure if it is safe to dereference it or not.  Suppose you passed begin() and end() from an empty vector, for example.  By returning an iterator the caller makes the decision to dereference (or not).  This also solves the problem of returning a value or reference.  The call is then just `median(mvvec.begin(), myvec.end());` - add a deference if you need to.

## Algorithm refinement

`b` and `e` must be random access iterators since you are calling to `std::sort`. However the count is calculated inefficiently.  Consider simply using `auto count = e - b;` and `auto mid = count / 2;`  Use of `auto` will give you the correct difference_type, which is not always the same as int.  Typically it is ptrdiff_t but good iterator code shouldn't assume even that.
If you can't use `auto` then `typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::difference_type` is the correct type to use.

Answer (score 2):

Switch the order of template parameters:

```
template <class T, class RandomIterator> 
T median(RandomIterator b, RandomIterator e)
```

This way you need to pass only the type of T at the call:

```
median<int>(it1, it2);
```

Or, better yet, get rid of T altogether:

```
template <class RandomIterator> 
auto median(RandomIterator b, RandomIterator e) -> auto(*b)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify the return type as template argument. 
You can access the underlying type of an iterator using the following:

```
std::iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::value_type
```

If you still want to do that, then you have to specify the type of all template arguments explicitly because the compiler is not able to uniquely infer it by using the other types provided.

I would remove it altogether as in the following:

```
template <class RandomIterator>
std::iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::value_type median(RandomIterator b, RandomIterator e)
```

or even better using auto

```
    template <class RandomIterator>
   auto median(RandomIterator b, RandomIterator e)
```